# spring cloud stream with microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices

i've been roaming the internet for some explanations and as i'm new to this i may be confused.

so when we want to set a microservices architecture we will be needing our microservice to communicate asynchronously and that being done with kafka (in my case)

i followed a tutorial that is using **Spring Cloud Stream** in order to connect with a running kafka and make his microservice able to write msgs to a given topic and read from a given topic also.

so what i wanted to know is should everyone of my microservices integrate this mecanism? or should i have one microservice that integrates spring cloud stream and when we need something from kafka contact it ? (which seems unlogical to me)

i'm asking this because i'm using consul for service discovery and when i integrated spring cloud stream in the project i got this error :

> Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A default binder has been requested, but there is more than one binder available for 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.DirectWithAttributesChannel' : consul,kafka, and no default binder has been set.

Comment: if you can add  your properties and  pom/ build file it would help

Comment: i'm not intrested in solving the error as much as im intrested in undrestanding the working mecanism .. that's why i didnt post the pom and other details